# Setting style on two component types

Tags: css

I seem to have got some brain stuck-up.

How should I design a CSS to include *h1* and *p* that are classed *intro*?!

This will target **all** *h1*s and *p*s.

```
h1, p { ... }
```

but this

```
h1, p .intro { ... }
```

only targets *h1* classed as *intro*, without affecting the *p*s that are classed *intro*. What's the syntax for that (so I don't have to define the following?

```
h1.intro { ... }
p.intro { ... }
```

I've also tested the following, without success.

```
h1.intro, p. intro { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost correct. Skip the blank at *p*.

```
h1.intro, p.intro { ... }
```

When used as the OP pasted it, i.e.

```
h1.intro, p .intro { ... }
```

the interpretor will see a class called *intro* not connected to a context of anything, i.e. equivalent to the following.

```
h1.intro, .intro { ... }
```

Comment: @CRMconfusee: while I don't feel that this answer was massively useful (and certainly lacked explanation), it does seem a little harsh to punitively down-vote someone for not posting (optional) demos on an external site.

Comment: @DavidThomas I agree with you but, after all, it's a community powered voting system. Also, I appreciate that he actually explained himself and stated his option. One has got to respect that. I really dislike when people downvote ones post cowardly saying nothing. That's borderline bullying, in my view. I'm just glad I saw the excessive space first and that we together could help the OP. This kind of answer can kick in after many months and give one +100 rep in a single day so I'll be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a comma to separate the selectors:

```
h1.intro,
p.intro {
 /*...*/
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ERssX/1/).

Or you could define all the common styles and then override only specific styles for those elements with that class:

```
.intro {
    /* ...all generic default styles */
}

p.intro,
h1.intro {
    /* specific style overrides for the h1 and p elements of this class */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ERssX/).

The reason that:

```
h1.intro, p. intro
```

doesn't work (depending on your evaluation of 'works' in this context) is that this will style an `h1` of class `intro`, but will style an element of class `intro` that is a descendant of a `p` element, the space between the `p` and the `.intro` implies a descendant relationship.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson No you didn't. You think you did but you really didn't. See my answer. :)

Comment: That's likely due to the typo.

Comment: I can swear that this space wasn't there before! Sight... I knew it was a brain-damaged question.